# Tridion 2011 SP1 - Transport service failed to transport

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When I publish I get the following error:

```
Transport service failed to transport. <Summary state="Failed" referenceId="tcm:0-122-66560"><Error>Transport failed for transaction: tcm:0-122-66560. Error while generating transaction summary.null</Error><Processing><Context topic="Content Delivery"><IsRollbackOnFailure /></Context></Processing><Target /></Summary>
```

The cd_core.log contains the following:

```
2012-07-09 13:41:07,497 DEBUG TransportService - Starting handing of a transaction
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 INFO  TransactionProcessor - No existing transport transaction information for: tcm:0-121-66560 creating new transaction state
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-121-66560 control=COMMIT] to C:\Temp\tcm_0-121-66560.Content\t
ransaction.xml
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG InstructionEncoder - Transaction state could not be serialized to file. Serialization error.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG InstructionEncoder - Transaction state could not be serialized to file. Serialization error.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 INFO  TransportService - Starting transport handling of transaction: tcm:0-121-66560
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 INFO  TransportPoolManager - Creating a new TransportPoolConnector, because no available connectors in connection pool
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG TransportPoolConnector - Configuring TransportPoolConnector.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Starting retrieving active transactions at destination: EkJ8TTiKBx4qU16og0f3wg==
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Found 0 transactions in progress and 0 waiting transactions.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: Local[Location[c:\tridion\incoming]] available: 1
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 INFO  DestinationController - Transaction fits inside current window, proceeding transaction: tcm:0-121-66560
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG TransactionManager - Destination is available for transport: EkJ8TTiKBx4qU16og0f3wg==
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG TransactionManager - All destinations are available for transport of transaction: tcm:0-121-66560
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG InstructionEncoder - Transaction state could not be serialized to file. Serialization error.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 INFO  ZipWorker - Preparing TransportPackage for id: tcm:0-121-66560
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping Transportpackage: c:\Temp\tcm_0-121-66560.Content
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-121-66560.Content/components.xml
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-121-66560.Content/instructions.xml
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-121-66560.Content/Pages/Test Website/_XSL/Nav.xsl
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-121-66560.Content/pages.xml
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-121-66560.Content/Schemas/tcm_10-25-8
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-121-66560.Content/schemas.xml
2012-07-09 13:41:07,513 DEBUG ZipUtils - Adding tcm_0-121-66560.Content/transaction.xml
2012-07-09 13:41:07,529 DEBUG InstructionEncoder - Transaction state could not be serialized to file. Serialization error.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,529 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping has been completed for transaction: tcm:0-121-66560
2012-07-09 13:41:07,529 DEBUG StepPrepare - Zipping has been completed successfully for transaction: tcm:0-121-66560
2012-07-09 13:41:07,529 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,529 DEBUG InstructionEncoder - Transaction state could not be serialized to file. Serialization error.
2012-07-09 13:41:07,529 ERROR TransactionManager - Error while generating transaction summary.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: null
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at com.tridion.util.JAXBUtil.registerContext(JAXBUtil.java:93) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.JAXBUtil.getContext(JAXBUtil.java:68) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.JAXBUtil.marshalToString(JAXBUtil.java:107) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.StepPrepare.execute(StepPrepare.java:49) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.transport(TransactionProcessor.java:63) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.TransactionManager.transport(TransactionManager.java:38) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:228) [cd_transport.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/ContextFactory
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if the jaxb-impl.jar is present in %TRIDION_HOME%\lib? If not, copy it from the installation cd.

Comment: Hi Quirijn - Thanks for the quick reply. Yes there is a jaxb-impl.jar and jaxb-api.jar in the Tridion/lib folder.

Comment: I saw the same error in Sites 9.1

Comment: @JanH I'm also seeing this in Sites 9.1, did you find a solution? Randomly, some of my publishing is failing with this error

Comment: This error due to multiple versions of java, I had a similar issue in sites 9.5 and noticed I had java 8 and opendjdk 11, uninstalled java 8 and fixed this issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check your ..\Tridion\lib\ folder - if the files:

jaxb-api.jar

jaxb-impl.jar

are there, remove them, restart the Publisher & Transport services, and re-test.

Comment: This also worked for me when moving from 2011 sp1 to 2013 sp1. They seemed to come in with the si4t jars.. Makes me a bit nervous..