# Tridion Publisher stopped working

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1.  Suddenly (it sounds silly, but I haven't changed any settings) my publishing stopped working.  The only thing I recall doing was deleting everything from the "incoming" folder assuming that Tridion would re-create everything it needs inside.

The error that I see in the Event Viewer is:

```
Transport service failed to transport. <Summary state="Failed" referenceId="tcm:0-1317-66560"><Error>Transport failed for transaction: tcm:0-1317-66560. Error while generating transaction summary.null</Error><Processing><Context topic="Content Delivery"><IsRollbackOnFailure /></Context></Processing><Target /></Summary>


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.SendTransportPackage(TransportPackage package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.HandlePublishRequest(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()
```

Then upon checking the cd_transport.log I see the following:

```
2013-01-04 01:13:56,359 DEBUG DestinationController - Checking destination for transport metadata
2013-01-04 01:13:56,360 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-04 01:13:56,360 DEBUG FileTransportConnector - Retrieving notification file if present: c:\tridion\incoming\meta.xml
2013-01-04 01:13:56,362 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: Local[Location[c:\tridion\incoming]] available: 1
2013-01-04 01:13:56,362 DEBUG DestinationController - Starting polling on destination: EkJ8TTiKBx4qU16og0f3wg==
2013-01-04 01:13:56,363 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-04 01:13:56,363 DEBUG FileTransportConnector - Retrieving notification file if present: c:\tridion\incoming\tcm_0-1319-66560.state.xml
2013-01-04 01:13:56,363 DEBUG FileTransportConnector - Retrieving notification file if present: c:\tridion\incoming\tcm_0-1317-66560.state.xml
2013-01-04 01:13:56,363 DEBUG FileTransportConnector - Retrieving notification file if present: c:\tridion\incoming\tcm_0-1318-66560.state.xml
2013-01-04 01:13:56,363 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: Local[Location[c:\tridion\incoming]] available: 1
2013-01-04 01:13:56,363 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 17 for transaction: tcm:0-1318-66560 on destination: EkJ8TTiKBx4qU16og0f3wg==
2013-01-04 01:13:56,363 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 10 for transaction: tcm:0-1319-66560 on destination: EkJ8TTiKBx4qU16og0f3wg==
2013-01-04 01:13:56,363 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 53 for transaction: tcm:0-1317-66560 on destination: EkJ8TTiKBx4qU16og0f3wg==
2013-01-04 01:13:56,532 ERROR RollingStateRetriever - Unable to deserialize transaction
2013-01-04 01:13:57,538 ERROR RollingStateRetriever - Unable to deserialize transaction
2013-01-04 01:13:58,547 ERROR RollingStateRetriever - Unable to deserialize transaction
2013-01-04 01:13:59,552 ERROR RollingStateRetriever - Unable to deserialize transaction
2013-01-04 01:14:00,558 ERROR RollingStateRetriever - Unable to deserialize transaction
```

The cd_core.log also shows an error:

```
ERROR RollingStateRetriever - Unable to deserialize transaction
```

The incoming folder has Transactions, Zip subfolders - both empty and a meta.xml file.

Can someone please suggest why this error is occuring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tridion 2011 SP1 - Transport service failed to transport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395886/tridion-2011-sp1-transport-service-failed-to-transport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a duplicate of:
[Tridion 2011 SP1 - Transport service failed to transport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395886/tridion-2011-sp1-transport-service-failed-to-transport)

Since my error logs were slightly different, so I'm keeping this in for others' future reference.